# Problem in selecting the ListBox selectedindex in ASP.Net:

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have one ListBox which has three Items in it. And also has one GridView and One Button.

I want to move the selected items in the listbox to the GridView when the Button is clicked.

Now the problem is, if I selects the third item in the listbox and clicks the button, It always moves the first item in the ListBox to the GridView.

How to solve this?

```
    <asp:ListBox ID="lbDrawing" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" Height="260px"  TabIndex="12" Width="150px"></asp:ListBox>
```

In the Button click event, I select the item by the following C# code,

string itemsname = lbDrawing.Items[lbDrawing.SelectedIndex].Text;

Anyone please help me.

Here, I fill the ListBox based the DropDownList SelectedIndex Changed Event. So I can not bind the ListBox in the Page is not PostBack Block.

Comment: Have you tried For each loop ?

Comment: @Mitul: No, I havent tried. On which basis I have to do loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like that the listbox is being bound even in the postback. Check and make sure that the DataBind of the listbox is within the `if (!IsPostBack) {}` block.

Comment: actually I am filling the listbox in the DropDownList selectedindex changed event. So i can not place it inside the Not Post Back block.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        foreach (ListItem lst in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            if (lst.Selected)
            {
                //TODO: Apply checked logic here.
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: You could use the `SelectedItems` property of the `ListBox`. Using the collection will eliminate the requirement for an `if-block`.